# WPGlobus not working when using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple Wordpress-sites at same server in subdirectories and I have alias domains for each of them. I am having trouble with one of them. I'm using .htaccess RewriteRule as follows

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.firstexamplesite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !firstexamplesite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ firstexamplesite/$1
```

The problem is I'm using WPGlobus-plugin to make site multilingual and it's working fine when I am using site through that subfolder. For example:

```
www.myfirstsite.com/myfirstsite/en
```

But when I am using site directly

```
www.myfirstsite.com
```

Language swithing button doesn't work. And when I'm trying to switch language directly, for example:

```
www.myfirstsite.com/en
```

I get that "Oops! That page can’t be found"-page of Wordpress

I'm guessing problem is related to .htaccess-file, but not sure

Comment: If each subfolder has its own WordPress installation, why do you need those .htaccess rules? http://demo-subfolder.wpglobus.com/ has two sites, and no special rules needed. If you have only one WP installation, then it's probably a multisite. Is it? Then again, no rules need. Please share more info.